# Joining records based on reference number and closest date

Tags: date, join, sas

I have two tables. One is information on letters sent out. This has upto two personal reference numbers in it (two columns, Person1 and Person2) and an estimated doormat drop date. The second table is a list of calls received. This has the personal reference number of the person who made the call (could be either person1 or person2 in the first table) and the date that the call was received. So:

Letters:
Person1
Person2
DoormatDate

Calls:
Person
Date

Each group can receive multiple letters and each person can make multiple calls. Oh and just to complicate things further, each person can appear in different groups with a different person or on their own for example.

What I need to do is match/join each call, once and once only, to the most recent letter received by that person (regardless of whether they occupy the person1 or person2 column) so that the call comes after the letter (we're looking at contact generation). Where it doesn't generate contact is as important as where it does so I'm thinking a left/right join will be in order.

The only way I've been able to think of approaching this is creating a unique reference number on both, perform a join between the two tables that gives me all of the possible combinations of letters and calls for each person over the year, calculate the difference in days and take the minimum difference for each call. That would be very processor intensive and I don't think would make the match unique (there are cases where there are more letter than calls and so I think the same call could end up being matched twice?!).

Any ideas? I can't quite get my head around this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Comment: It's sas, although I tend to write in SQL when I use it. Is it less confusing for everyone if I delete the SQL reference?

Comment: I've removed the SQL mention just in case that confuses things.

Comment: I think you are correct in that this is more of an optimization problem and less of a query problem.

Comment: How many records are we talking about in each table?

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know where to start.

Single digit millions of both.

Comment: You could use my answer below.  Break it into small work chunks.  That is, take only X number of calls at a time.  That would reduce the time to compute the Cartesian product.  Play with the value of X to find the optimal size.

Comment: My main issue I think is that to calculate what the nearest date of letter is, you need to know the number of days between the call and all of the letters received by that individual. To do that, you need to join the table to each other, but that requires you to have already joined all of the records to each other already.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if your number of records is not too huge, I think you can do this with a constrained Cartesian product and then a Data Step (just to be SAS-y).

I assume tables are

```
Letters (
   letter_id ,
   person1 ,
   person2 ,
   DoorMatDate
)

Calls (
   call_id ,
   person ,
   CallDate
)
```

So do the join while calculating the distance.  Order the results.

```
proc sql noprint;

create table letters_x_calls as
select a.letter_id,
       b.call_id,
       b.person,
       b.CallDate,
       a.DoorMatDate,
       b.CallDate - a.DoorMatDate as timeToCall
    from letters as a,
         calls as b
    where (b.person = a.person1 or b.person = a.person2)
      and b.CallDate > a.DoorMatDate
    order by call_id, timeToCall;

quit;
```

Then use a Data Step with a by statement to keep only the first record.

```
data letters_x_calls;
   set letters_x_calls;
   by call_id timetocall;

   if first.call_id;
run;
```

You could obviously do this in SQL calculating the `min(timeToCall)` and using a `HAVING` statement, too.

Comment: I've had to break it up to get it working (I tried to run the whole thing overnight and 17 hours later it was still going) so I've broken up the letters data on a monthly basis and I've run those against that month and three months forward. It still takes a couple of hours but SAS seems to manage it. Append these back together isn't a big deal.

As I'm interested in the cases where there has been no call, I'll match these records back onto the main letters database using a left hand join on the letters_id.

Thank you.

Comment: happy to help.  If I think of a faster way to do this, I'll post it.

Comment: keep the distance metric.  After you append the results, resort and rerun that data step to keep the one with the lowest distance.

Comment: I've just realised there's an issue with breaking it up like that though. It runs the risk of matching the same call being matched to different letters. I think I might be able to tidy it up, but it involves a very iterative process (including deleting calls already matched from future datasets I think). Hm

Comment: Sorry, I've messed up the order of the conversation fixing a type.
The example I've thinking of is

17Jan:Letter,

21Feb: Letter,

23Feb: Call

25Feb: Call.

I was thinking that both letters would get matched to the 23Feb phone call. i don't think there's a way of getting around that. I could scratch out the second but given I'm trying to measure contact ratios I need the second call to match to the second letter given that the first call is matched to the first letter.

Comment: Actually, both calls will get matched to the second letter as its call_id referred to in the data step. The longer (later) one will then get removed. Am I misunderstanding what will happen?

Comment: Correct.  Do a couple of searches to get a handle on BY processing in the data step.  What this does is only keep the first record for each call.  Because you have sorted the data in ascending order of distance, that means the smallest distance is kept.

Comment: Thank you. I'll speak to a colleague to see if this is an issue. I think our main problem might be we're trying to answer too many questions with the same data matching exercise.